# C# null-conditional shorthand for method arguments

Tags: c#, null, null-conditional-operator

The null-conditional operator is very useful when the method belongs to the object in question, but what if the object in question is an argument? For example, can this be shortened?

```
var someList = new List<SomeType>();
if (anotherList.Find(somePredicate) != null)
{
    someList.Add(anotherList.Find(somePredicate))
}
```

One solution I thought of was to use an extension method like below:

```
public static void AddTo<T>(this T item, List<T> list)
{
    list.Add(item);
}
```

With that the first code block can be reduced to:

```
var someList = new List<SomeType>();
anotherList.Find(somePredicate)?.AddTo(someList);
```

But this solution is specific to this example (i.e. adding an object to a list if it's not null). Is there a general way to indicate that if a parameter is null, the method should not be run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never do this

```
var someList = new List<SomeType>();
if (anotherList.Find(somePredicate) != null)
{
    someList.Add(anotherList.Find(somePredicate))
}
```

this will search the list twice which is unnecessary. use a temporary variable instead.

```
var someList = new List<SomeType>();
var find = anotherList.Find(somePredicate);
if (find != null) someList.Add(find);
```

---

> Is there a general way to indicate that if a parameter is null, the method should not be run?

Currently there is no such feature. how ever there are other alternatives that work better like in other answers provided.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! The first block of code was meant to be an example of undesirable code. One of the reasons why I wanted something like the null-conditional operator is because it evaluates the object only once without having to explicitly declare a temporary variable.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use just:

```
var someList = new List<SomeType>();
someList.AddRange(anotherList.Where(somePredicate));
```

In your case you probably need to make sure that your predicate only finds at max one element.

Comment: good solution. you can use `Take(1)` to only pick the first element.

Comment: I guess if you use `Take(1)`, you should also use `OrderBy(predicate)` - otherwise the result may be arbitrary.

Comment: Adding a possibly null object to a list was just an example for my question about coming up with a shorthand for possibly null parameters in general, but thank you for the suggestion! It was very informative.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Not yet.

The team plans to implement a functionality into the language, that would do this exact thing. It would look something like this:

```
someList.Add(anotherList.Find(somePredicate) ?? return);
```

In which the `?? return` checks whether the first argument is null, and if it is, than it returns. (Or you could write break if that is what you want)

I am not sure if this is a thing they are working on at the moment, and if it will be included in the next version of C#, but would go a long way if it is going to be.

Comment: this will not work if this is not the last line in your method. you may want to continue the method instead of returning from it. I believe `break` would only work inside loops.